# Can't start ubuntuone-installer

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, kubuntu

Hi all I'm running kubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying to run ubuntu one, but I get this error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
maurizio@maurizio-desktop:~$ ubuntuone-installer  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/bin/ubuntuone-installer", line 39, in <module>
dialog = Window()   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer/ubuntuone/installer/gui.py", line 105, in __init__
    _(u'Discover the freedom of your personal cloud'))) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first trying like this:

`LC_ALL=C ubuntuone-installer`

But if that does not work , according to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-installer/+bug/867803) there is a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-installer/+bug/867803/comments/5) for this issue.

First, install the needed package:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel`

And then configure you account.

`ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk`

If that does not work, just uninstall all the Ubuntu One packages and do this again.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my problem. Any idea why I was having an issue in the first place^

Comment: I think this is a problem with Python and your system language.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk
```

remove/install did it for me, now the ubuntu one icon in system settings will launch.

I'm running english/new zealand.  Is this broken for all non-american english speakers?